# How to show empty table using jquery.datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery.dataTables.js to show my table data, but on initial load, I want an empty table and after when I select some filters then accordingly table loads data.
I also use iDeferLoading but it requires some initial data to load, but I want an empty table

- version     1.9.4
- file        jquery.dataTables.js

Code - jsfiddle.net/anki18/Lx97wouy

Comment: If you want an empty table, initialise it on a html table with no rows and then add 
new rows programatically

Comment: That's exactly the question, how to do it?

Comment: The process is exactly the same regardless of how much data is in the table. Just follow the user guide on the Datatables site

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the following way

**HTML CODE**

```
<table id="new-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$("#new-table").DataTable();
```

You can initialize the DataTable with your required options

**Edit**
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upm5Lneb/)

Comment: Not working, if I do this it is giving me alert box and message is -

DataTables warning (table id = 'new-table'): Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0

Comment: @AnkitVaidya in that case you need to update the question to show the code you're using, as you're doing something wrong. This code works fine

Answer (score 0):

You will get errors if you create a table without proper html tags

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ko21pacg/2/) example

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Hired Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<button id="addButton">
Click me to add new rows
</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.dataTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();

    $('#addButton').click(function() {
        window.dataTable.rows.add([
            [
                "Tiger Nixon",
                "System Architect",
                "$3,120",
                "2011/04/25"
            ],
            [
                "Garrett Winters",
                "Director",
                "$5,300",
                "2011/07/25"
            ]
        ]).draw()
    })
});
```

Comment: Here is my code which calls api on initial load -
https://jsfiddle.net/anki18/Lx97wouy/